# Qt: QMutex member in derived QList<XYZ>, no access to QMutex member compile error

Tags: c++, qt4

I have a derived `QList<MyClass>`, with a member `QMutex`.

```
class WaypointList : public QList<Waypoint> {
private:
    mutable QMutex _mutex; /*!< Mutex for thread safety */
    ..
} // HERE COMPILE ERROR, in this line
```

Compiling, I get `C2248: 'QMutex::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class 'QMutex'`

The reason is that `QMutex` is not copyable (`Q_DISABLE_COPY`, [related SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652504/how-do-i-copy-object-in-qt)). Here it is recommended [to make the member a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507604/cannot-access-private-member-declared-in-class-qreadwritelockerror1error-c22). **Is that the best way to do it?**

Remarks:

1. When I use `QMutex _mutex` in a derived `Q_OBJECT` class, it works fine. Any idea why I get the error here and not with a `Q_OBJECT` class?
2. In other languages I'd declare the member as transient. Actually I do **not** want to have it copied. Is there a declaration for just ignoring it?
3. Or is writing an assignment / copy operator the better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't have an issue with QObject is that QObject is also non-copyable, so it's not an issue.

In your case, the correct answer is to define your own copy and assignment operators, so that they copy/assign the list, but the object has it's own mutex.  That way, it will behave as you expect.  There is no keyword in C++ to tell the compiler you want this behavior, you have to do it yourself.  In this case, since it's a mutex, you'll probably want to use the mutex properly to ensure the copy is atomic.

Another option is to disable copying/assignment on your new class, but from your question I don't believe that is what you want to do.  Finally, if you do decide to use a pointer to the QMutex, you will probably want to create your own copy/assignment operators to handle the raw pointer properly, to prevent a leak.

Comment: You got it right, I'd prefer to keep "copy", and need the mutex during copy and assignment from different threads. I give it a trial with own operator (and then I'll be back :-)

Answer (score 1):

`Q_OBJECT` is a macro that must appear in the private section of a class definition that declares its own signals and slots or that uses other services provided by Qt's meta-object system ([here](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT)). This macro requires the class to be a subclass of `QObject`. `QObject` has neither a copy constructor nor an assignment operator ([take a look here](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qobject.html#no-copy-constructor-or-assignment-operator)).

Sorry if I repeat something that you know. I would suggest to disable explicitly copy constructor and assignment operator of your class with a `Q_DISABLE_COPY` macro:

```
class WaypointList : public QList<Waypoint> {
private:
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(WaypointList)
    mutable QMutex _mutex; /*!< Mutex for thread safety */
    ..
};
```

Hope, this will help.

Comment: This also works, but I stick with a version of the class I can copy (=> assignment operator implemented). Thanks for your hint.